# Datasets for Genetic Diversity of Species Across Geographical Distribution

Tags: bioinformatics, ecology, population-genetics, data, conservation-biology

I'm carrying out some research on applying machine learning methods to ecology and conservation. I'd like to know: are there some datasets on genetic diversity across geographical positions? Preferably:

1. Being well-established and trusted
2. Including multiple species

Information regarding any similar or related resources will also be highly appreciated. Thanks a bunch in advance, community!

Comment: To clarify; Are you asking for datasets that compare differences in genetic diversity between populations within the same species at different geographical sites?

Comment: @fileunderwater Not exactly, but I'm so desperate that it would do if there is one :-D

Comment: Ok, so what you are after are multi-species summaries of single/point estimates of genetic diversity in the different species, along with geographic location(?). Multiple estimates for each species from different populations are not necessary(?).

Comment: @fileunderwater just anything of the kind please

Comment: I’m just a bit confused, in the sense that different types of studies and reviews that contain some measure of genetic diversity shouldn’t be too rare or hard to find. If you are looking for more specific types of data, length of study periods or specific methods used that might be another thing. But your question is quite general at the moment. What about this paper or humans and primates; could this be useful to you? [Osada, 2015, *Genetic diversity in humans and non-human primates and its evolutionary consequences*](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26510568/)

Comment: @fileunderwater Thanks but are there larger datasets?

Comment: There probably is, but this isn’t really my area, so I don’t know. Doing some careful literature searches shouldn’t be difficult though. You best bet is probably to do some structured searches to find 5-10 studies of the type I linked and then combining the data from all of them for you training/review study.

Comment: @fileunderwater Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what the scope of your research is, but if you are just trying to see if you can successfully apply "machine learning methods" to certain datasets, have you thought about just generating the datasets? Forgive me if I'm making wrong assumptions, but it just seems strange for relevant datasets not to be provided by whoever might interested in gaining real insights on "genetic diversity across geographical positions". Isn't your research overseen or financed by an institution? Just hard to believe that hunting for data would be a more significant part of your study than applying whatever machine learning algorithms are necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I didn't make the scope of my research clear. I want to use methods on REAL data instead of generated ones to evaluate their effectiveness in the task. In other words, the "real insights" you mentioned is the genuinely key part of our research.

Comment: Oh and regarding the institution part, our research is funded but they are interested in the methods. So WE need the results for validation, but the funders aren't so much interested in the detailed results of one single test.